# Trying to display a rectangle in libGDX (android)

Tags: java, android, libgdx, 2d, collision

```
    platformR = new ShapeRenderer();
    platformR.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    platformR.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    platformR.identity();
    platformR.setColor(new Color(0, 1, 0, 1));
    platformR.rotate(0, 0, 1, 90);*/
    platformR.rect(getxPos(), getyPos(), getSprite().getWidth() + getxPos(),
            getSprite().getHeight() + getxPos());
    platformR.end();
```

This is the code I have for displaying a rectangle, but the rectangle doesn't display. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you place your .begin() / .end() method calls in the render() method.

```
public class ShapeRendererExample extends ApplicationAdapter {
ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;

@Override
public void create () {
    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
}

@Override
public void render () {
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(new Color(1, 0, 0, 1));
    shapeRenderer.rect(100f, 100f, 100f, 100f);
    shapeRenderer.end();
}

private void clearScreen()
{
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am trying to draw a rectangle in my Platform class (a tile that the Player can collide with). I tried what you said in the update() method in Platform then called Platform.update() in the main class' render() method. Still no results, have I done it correctly?